# mvc c# combine more than two query results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have several generic queries that has the same structure of results and I'm trying to combine them in one variable so that I can pass them to the view.

```
var query1 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter1).Select(x=> new ViewModel { //columns}).LastOrDefault();
var query2 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter2).Select(x=> new ViewModel  { //columns}).LastOrDefault();
var query3 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter3).Select(x=> new ViewModel  { //columns}).LastOrDefault();

var combi = query1.Concat(query2);
```

I cannot combine the two query results, I tried using Concat or Union but it gives the error below.

'ViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'ViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using DB first, better to use stored procedure instead of this.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to replace the `var` keyword with the actual types you'd see that you have this:

```
ViewModel query1 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter1).Select(x => new ViewModel { /* columns */ }).LastOrDefault();
ViewModel query2 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter2).Select(x=> new ViewModel { /* columns */ }).LastOrDefault();
ViewModel query3 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter3).Select(x=> new ViewModel { /* columns */ }).LastOrDefault();
```

In order to do a `.Concat(...)` it should be `IQueryable<ViewModel>` or `IEnumerable<ViewModel>`.

It's the `.LastOrDefault()` call that is causing you grief.

Try this:

```
IQueryable<ViewModel> query1 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter1).Select(x => new ViewModel { /* columns */ });
IQueryable<ViewModel> query2 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter2).Select(x=> new ViewModel { /* columns */ });
IQueryable<ViewModel> query3 = db1.table.Where(a => a.ID == filter3).Select(x=> new ViewModel { /* columns */ });

var combi = query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: wiil the `LastOrDefault()` on the variable `combi` work like how it works on the individual query?

Comment: @makoto - Yes, it should do.