# why does LastOrDefault conflicts with IEnumerable<Viewmodel>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to merge several query results and it works by using  `IEnumerable<Viewmodel>` as type per query and I use `concat` to combine but I cannot use `LastOrDefault()` per query - [combine more than two results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394192/mvc-c-sharp-combine-more-than-two-query-results)

But I need to specify that the query will return only the Last value and will return none if it is null , but there is an error.

I already tried `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` but still it gave me an error.

EDIT: 
the three queries have the same structures on the columns returned

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> query1= db.Table1
                        .Where(er => er.ID == Filter1) 
                        .Select(er => new ViewModel
                         {
                           //columns here 
                         }).ToList().LastOrDefault(); //the **ToList().LastOrDefault();** shows error but I need this to get only the last row from the query if there is

IEnumerable<ViewModel> query2= db.Table2
                        .Where(er => er.ID == Filter2) 
                        .Select(er => new ViewModel
                         {
                           //columns here 
                         }).ToList().LastOrDefault(); //the **ToList().LastOrDefault();** shows error but I need this to get only the last row from the query if there is

IEnumerable<ViewModel> query3= db.Table3
                        .Where(er => er.ID == Filter3) 
                        .Select(er => new ViewModel
                         {
                           //columns here 
                         }).ToList().LastOrDefault(); //the **ToList().LastOrDefault();** shows error but I need this to get only the last row from the query if there is

var result = query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3).ToList();//it shows error here if I add the **ToList().LastOrDefault()** per query
```

if I add the **LastOrDefault()** on the result statement it will show only one row which is from the **query3**

How can I fix this? Thank you so much, please be patient to me.

Comment: try posting some code its not clear from what your saying.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. It is rather unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Because `Concat()` is an extension method of `IEnumerable` (not a single object which `.LastOfDefault()` generates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say the best way is to override `List<T>`, but if your project is to small for this and this is the only place where you need it you could make it like this:

```
List<ViewModel> list1 = new List<ViewModel>();

var query1 = db.Table1.Where(er => er.ID == Filter1)
                      .Select(er => new ViewModel
                        {
                            //columns here 
                        }).ToList().LastOrDefault(); 
list1.Add(query);

var query2 = db.Table2.Where(er => er.ID == Filter2)
                      .Select(er => new ViewModel
                        {
                            //columns here 
                        }).ToList().LastOrDefault(); 
list1.Add(query);

var query3 = db.Table3.Where(er => er.ID == Filter3)
                      .Select(er => new ViewModel
                        {
                            //columns here 
                        }).ToList().LastOrDefault();

list1.Add(query);

return list1;
```

Comment: Why having 3 lists that you `Concat` after? Just add the items to a single list

Comment: You are right... sure...

Comment: @Julia, thanks... that was very helpful. I combined the list query results using list. **PS: I need to separate several queries because I need to sort them exactly**

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to concat stuff or or forward-declaring lists and adding elements as you go etc. You can simply select the items one by one and materialize them into a list as follows:

```
var a = table
    .Where(PredicateA)
    .Select(Selector)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var b = table
    .Where(PredicateB)
    .Select(Selector)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var c = table
    .Where(PredicateC)
    .Select(Selector)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var result = new[] {a, b, c};
```

Or you can select them all together in a single query (probably better performance-wise, but favor what you think is more readable).

```
var result = table
    .Where(x => PredicateA(x) || PredicateB(x) || PredicateC(x))
    .Select(Selector);
```

Comment: I cannot use your this option because, the filters are not on one column only, I filter it with different column, due to the complicated business logic, thank you for your answer.

Comment: what prevents you from using the solution? a lambda can be an arbitrarily complex code block and can take any amount of parameters (not to mention the fact the my current example sends the whole row to some undefined predicate).

Comment: hmm, that is very helpful and I understand your point but I am not very confident on the sequence of output when using this, just like my comment on the other answer, I need to do the manual because of the sequence. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

LastOrDefault gives you not an `IEnumerable` but only one element. And you try to assign it to `IEnumerable`. That is your problem. In your case I would rewrite `LastOrDefault` (or use another function instead of it) so it returns a `IEnumerable` with only one element you need.

Comment: if you would use another function, what would it be? I tried Take(1) but it conflicts will null results.